# jeasyui ajax help needed

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-easyui

I'm using jeasyUI and want to implement a tree style file grid. My code works fine for retrieving the items (tree) from my mysql db, displaying it and letting it be dropped and dragged, but I have no idea how to implement the AJAX part to upload the changes when you reorder the items. I included the sample code but it doesn't work. To be honest, I'm a newbie at AJAX, although I have worked with it a little in the past. Could anyone point me in the right direction of what I should do. I know PHP, Mysql and am currently learning JQUERY and Javascript.

```
    <script>
    $(function(){
        $('#tt2').tree({
            dnd: true,
            url:'sql/tree2_getdata.php',                
            onClick: function(node){
                $(this).tree('beginEdit',node.target);
            },
            onDrop: function(targetNode, source, point){

                var targetId = $(target).tree('getNode', targetNode).id;
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'sql/tree2_putdata.php',
                    type: 'post',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {
                        id: source.id,
                        targetId: targetId,
                        point: point
                    }
                }); 
            }
        }); 
        });
</script>
<h2>File List</h2>
<ul id="tt2"></ul>
```

Comment: it's really help if you provide your tree2_putdata.php code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this

```
$.ajax({
                    url: 'sql/tree2_putdata.php',
                    type: 'post',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {
                        id: source.id,
                        targetId: targetId,
                        point: point
                    },
                    success: function(data){
                      $(this).tree('reload');
                    }
                });
```

and make sure you do update the order of the tree on your `tree2_putdata.php` file

hope that can help you